# How to enlarge a Matplotlib group bar diagram

Tags: matplotlib

I have a group bar chart that I would like to scale.

I am running matplotlib in a Jupyter Notebook and the bar chart is very squashed. I would like to make the axis bigger but can't get it to work in a group bar chart. If I could make it wider it would be much more readable. But if I just increase "width" then the bars start to overlap each other.

The second problem is what to do about the labels. How can the labels be printed to three decimal places?

Note: I recognise that the the values plotted are orders of magnitude different so you cannot really read the small values. Ordinarily you would not combine these onto a single chart - but this is a class exercise to demonstrating why you would not do it so I expect that.

Here is the self-contained code to demonstrate the problem:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

labels = ['0-9', '10-19', '20-29', '30-39', '40-49', '50-59', '60-69', '70-79', '80-89', '90-99']
t3=[1.2833333333333332, 1.6970588235294117, 1.7189655172413794, 1.8090163934426229, 1.44140625, 1.5763157894736846, 1.3685185185185187, 1.430120481927711, 1.5352941176470587, 1.9]
tt4= [116.33333333333333, 106.0, 106.93103448275862, 109.47540983606558, 98.734375, 99.84210526315789, 96.72839506172839, 99.40963855421687, 104.94117647058823, 203.0]
tsh= [1.2833333333333332, 1.6970588235294117, 1.7189655172413794, 1.8090163934426229, 1.44140625, 1.5763157894736846, 1.3685185185185187, 1.430120481927711, 1.5352941176470587, 1.9]
hypo_count= [2, 15, 55, 58, 59, 69, 72, 74, 33, 1]

x = np.arange(len(labels))  # the label locations
width = 0.2  # the width of the bars

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
rects1 = ax.bar(x, t3, width, label='T3 avg')
rects2 = ax.bar(x+(width), tt4, width, label='TT4 avg')
rects3 = ax.bar(x+(width*2), tsh, width, label='TSH avg')
rects4 = ax.bar(x+(width*3), hypo_count, width, label='# Hypothyroid +ve')

# Add some text for labels, title and custom x-axis tick labels, etc.
ax.set_title('Age Bracket')
ax.set_xticks(x)
ax.set_xticklabels(labels)
ax.legend()

# Print the value on top of each bar
ax.bar_label(rects1, padding=3)
ax.bar_label(rects2, padding=3)
ax.bar_label(rects3, padding=3)
ax.bar_label(rects4, padding=3)

fig.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: try to change the size with `fig.set_size_inches`

Comment: Yes - that certainly improved it. And I solved the rounding by using round() on the input data. Thanks

Comment: Best practice is to keep full precision in the data and just round the output strings: `ax.bar_label(rects1, padding=3, fmt='%.3f')`